# fb app post on users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, html

How to make a fb application that operates like this:

When a user visites a page of MY website ex. `http://www.mywebsite.com/page1.php` it will request the user to confirm the Facebook Application to make able the content of page, and then the application will post on users wall the page that the user visited on my page !?

Any idea, any script, any everything, I dont know how to even start it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, when the user enters your website ask him to login with facebook (ref: [login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)).
2. After the successful authorization, simply use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and post the link to current page on his wall.

Comment: do I need to cerate an Application for that ?

Comment: yes you have to make an app for that, that will generate the APP_ID and APP_SECRET that you would be using to integrate. What do you mean by " do I have to add code to the fb app ? "

Comment: I never created a fb app so I don't know if there is eny code to write btw thank you a lot..

Comment: read the docs, SDK samples and search here for any issue. its easy and not complicated at all. If my comment helped out, please mark it as correct answer.